# Как передать команду из Фрагмента_Б в Фрагмент_А что Фрагмент_Б закрылся

Tags: android, android-fragment

Открываю Фрагмент_А выполняю какие то действия, открываю Фрагмент_Б выполняю какие то действия хочу закрыть Фрагмент_Б и сказать Фрагменту_А что Фрагмент_Б закрылся.

onResume и onStart не срабатывают.
Фрагмент_А закрывать нельзя (данные удаляются).

Comment: а где в это время фрагмент А?

Comment: Фрагмент 1 (интерфэйс) => активити => nonull метод фрагмента 2

Comment: Я делал как написано здесь https://metanit.com/java/android/8.5.php может и вам подойдет, посмотрите